Debugging html outputs in pdf format
If a Quarto / RMarkdown file, which contains a code chunk that produces an html output, is rendered to a pdf format, an error is produced (see below) if {webshot} or {webshot2} is not installed.
This is expected, and the problem has been solved.
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting pdf output.
[...]

Execution halted

However, if I don't know which code chunk is the culprit for producing html output, the error message above is not helpful. The error message gives me no information of the chunk label and / or line number where the error originated.
My question is not: How do I prevent HTML outputs when rendering to pdf. My question is:
How do I find the chunk which produces HTML outputs?
Here is a minimal Quarto / Rmarkdown file that throws the mentioned error:

---
format: pdf
---


```{r}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```


```{r}
plotly::plot_ly(x = 1, y = 1)
```

In this example, it's easy to see the source of the error (chunk 2). In many cases, however, I would potentially have to analyse hundreds of code chunks. It becomes especially difficult, when output sensitive libraries are involved (e.g. knitr::kable produces html tables for html outputs and latex tables for pdf outputs).
